# Can I publish an alpha test without a release version?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I had an apk uploaded to a working version section of google play's developer console
and an apk - to alpha version.

The application is not ready but I needed an alpha testing to make in-app billing test.
But when I publish aplha test version - it publishes to google play openly as well.

And strangely, now I can't disable publishing app to public when publishing alpha test for testers. Is there a way to publish only alpha version?

Comment: `plz don't downvote` gives you an upvote :)

Comment: Probably not. Alternatively, use a service like HockeyApp.

Comment: is the alpha version higher than last published apk? did u choose open or closed alpha test?